# Казачок или казачёк - как правильно?

Tags: суффиксы

По правилам "казачок", однако во многих местах дается "казачёк", например:
[Словарь синонимов ASIS. В.Н. Тришин. 2013.](https://m.slovari.yandex.ru/spelling.xml?text)

Мы с товарищем спорим: я ему "казачок" и одни ссылки и правила, а он мне - "казачёк" и другие ссылки..
Разрешите наш спор, учитывая те ссылки, которые я привел.

Comment: А не могли бы ЭТИ ссылки дать, где казачЁк? Что-то я по всем словарям прошлась, не нашла. И по Вашей ссылке - ОК, вернее, пришлось слово вводить, а вышло оно с -ОК- и к нему синонимы. Дело в том, что в русском языке в суфф. существительных не может быть под ударением Ё. Во французском - да: дирижёр, стажёр, в русском е перешло в о под ударением после мягких согласных ещё в стародавние времена, возврата не было.Осталось  только в глаголах тушить-тушёнка.

Comment: Людмила, пройдитесь еще раз по ссылке автора и напишите казачЕк, и вам придет этот вариант.

Comment: http://onlineslovari.com/kazachiy_slovar_spravochnik/page/kazachek.723/

Comment: https://m.slovari.yandex.ru/spelling.xml?text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA

Comment: Не пойму, как здесь комментарии добавить, еще раз продублирую словари, в которых "казачЁк"

Answer (score 3):

Орфографический словарь под редакцией Лопатина предлагает вариант: казачок. Но и в других словарях  тоже зафиксирован этот вариант.

Указанный вами словарь единственный, который предлагает писать это слово через ***ё***. Однако обратите внимание, что в вашем словаре вариант казачЕк дается как вариативный наряду с казачок, который дан как основной.

В выборе написания то или иного слова надо ориентироваться на орфографические словари, а не синонимические. А указанный вами словарь именно синонимический.

> См.: Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
>   Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.
>
> Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
>   Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
>   Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
>
> Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.
>
> Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Answer (score 3):

> Мы с товарищем спорим: я ему "казачок" и одни ссылки и правила, а он
>   мне - "казачёк" и другие ссылки...

**Александр Львович! Похоже на то, что правы и Вы, и Ваш товарищ.**

Ну а почему так -- сейчас, к сожалению, нет времени написать. Часов через 20 постараюсь вернуться к этому вопросу.

================================================================

================================================================

***КАЗАЧ?К -- с "О" или "Ё"?***

В древние времена такого вопроса бы не возникло. После шипящих под ударением всегда писалось ***е***, т. к. такое написание вполне соответствовало произношению того времени. Но в дальнейшем, когда в русском языке ударяемое ***е*** перед твёрдым согласным стало звучать как ***о*** (***ё***), стали возникать колебания в написании. Ломоносов, Востоков и Буслаев склонялись в таких случаях к ***е***. Единообразия не было ни в словарях, ни у писателей. Даже один и тот же писатель писал по-разному в разных своих произведениях.

Так, в изданиях сочинений Пушкина, вышедших при его жизни,  имелись как написания с суффиксом ***ок*** (*кружокъ, горшокъ*), так и написания с суффиксом ***ек*** (*пятачекъ*).

Не было последовательности  и в словаре Соколова ("Общий церковно-славяно-российский словарь", 1834 г.):  *кушачекъ, кружекъ, косячекъ*, но *козачок*.

Имелись противоречивые написания и в "Словаре церковно-славянского и русского языка", вышедшем в середине 19-го века: *кабачек* (от *кабак*), написанное с ударным ***е***, но *кружек* (от *круг*).

[Тот же *казачок*, бывало,  писался и с ***ё***:](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5egMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

[image: https://books.google.ru/books?id=5egMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y]

Более-менее единообразное написание пошло от Грота, утвердившего своим авторитетом употребление ***о*** под ударением после шипящих в суффиксах и окончаниях (*сверчок, пушок, кружок, мечом…*).

Неоднократно предпринимались попытки распространить написание ***о*** под ударением после шипящих и на другие морфемы. В постановлении Орфографической комиссии 1904 года оно было сформулировано так: "После ***ж, ш, ц, ч, щ*** под ударением нужно писать всегда ***о***, если оно явственно слышится…". Рассматривалось такое предложение и в проекте Главнауки 1930 года. Рассматривалось и Орфографической комиссией в 1964 году. Предлагалось после шипящих практически во всех словах писать под ударением ***о***, без ударения -- ***е*** (*чорный, шолк, течот* и др.). "Предложения по усовершенствованию русской орфографии" были опубликованы в периодической печати.  Многие из читателей, обсуждавших этот проект, предлагали более интересное решение: под ударением после шипящих всегда писать ***ё***, без ударения -- ***е***. Если бы это предложение было принято, *казачёк* во всех своих значениях писался бы с ***ё***.

Букчина, Калакуцкая и Чельцова  в книге "Письма об орфографии" (1969) пишут:

> Принятие этого предложения решило бы некоторые трудности; оно
>   сохраняло бы единообразие морфемы, связь ударных и безударных форм, не
>   противоречило бы произношению. Но… было бы возможно лишь при
>   последовательном, узаконенном употреблении буквы ***ё***, чего, **к**
>   **сожалению**, нет.

Предложение это не было принято (как, впрочем, и все остальные предложения комиссии), и потому единственным нормативным вариантом в наше время является, конечно, написание слова ***казачок*** с ***о***, если… Если речь идёт о *казачках*, о которых говорится  в "Большом толковом словаре"!!!  У этих *казачков* ***ок*** -- суффикс, и потому надо руководствоваться  [правилом](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18):

> **§ 18.** После ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** для передачи ударного гласного ***о*** пишется буква ***о*** или ***ё.***
>
> Буква ***о*** пишется в следующих случаях.
>
> <…>
>
> 2. В суффиксах имен существительных:
>
> ***-ок***, напр.: ***кружок, крючок, петушок, борщок, прыжок, толчок…***

Что же до слова ***казачёк*** (с ***ё***) в словаре Тришина, то… Обратите внимание на то, что слова ***казачёк*** и ***казачок*** в этом словаре **не синонимичны**. Это совсем разные слова! 
У ***казачок*** синонимы -- *танец, челядин, челядинец, прислужник, холуй, служитель, слуга, казак, лакей, мальчик.* У ***казачёк*** же в числе синонимов только ***казачек***.

***Казачёк***  Тришиным вполне мог быть взят [отсюда](https://books.google.ru/books?id=EoppAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y):

[image: https://books.google.ru/books?id=EoppAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&dq=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y]

И писаться в таком случае ***казачёк*** должен именно с ***ё*** (никак не с ***о***).
Ударному звуку ***о*** в этом слове  соответствует в родительном падеже гласный, передаваемый буквой ***е*** (*"у **казачЕка** мех немного лучше"*), а потому написание  слова ***казачёк*** должно подчиняться совсем иному, чем у слова ***казачок***, [правилу](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18):

> **§ 19.** Во всех остальных случаях для передачи ударного гласного ***о*** после ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** пишется буква ***ё***, а именно:
>
> <...>
>
> 7. В тех корнях русских слов, где ударному звуку ***о*** соответствует в других однокоренных словах или формах гласный (ударный или
>      безударный), передаваемый буквой ***е***.

=====================================

**P.S.**

Несмотря но то, что слово ***казачок*** со значениями "уменьш.-ласк. к *Казак*",  "мальчик-слуга", "народный танец", должно было бы по правилам писаться с о, на практике это иногда нарушается. См. [примеры](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BA%22&tbm=bks).

Comment: Жду с нетерпением

Comment: Я там выше еще дал ссылки на пару словарей, где "казачёк"

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, куда падает  ударение в слове "казачек", может быть, на второй слог?

В коляске сидел камердинер батюшки, а на запятках **казачек**, бандурист. [Ф. В. Булгарин. Воспоминания (1846-1849)]

Сравнить: Один только **казачок** заснул весело и спокойно. [В. А. Соллогуб. Сережа (1838)

Comment: _Vera: Интересно, куда падает ударение в слове "казачек", может быть, на второй слог?_ === И опять не то... Вопрос-то был по варианту **казачёк** (с Ё) в словаре Тришина. В этом варианте ударение -- **на третьем** слоге. Почему Тришин включил в словарь этот вариант? Наверное, такое написание у кого-то имело место. А вот кто и почему писал именно так...

Comment: Вера, Фадддея Булгарина как пример брать нельзя, он же ярый враг Карамзина и его буквы Ё, на этом месте у него ВСЕГДА Е:простер,  взбредет http://az.lib.ru/b/bulgarin_f_w/text_0170.shtml

Comment: Я просто обратила внимание на написание "казачек", так как  в первой половине 19 века практически все пишут "казачок", вариант с буквой Ё "казачёк" вообще не встречается.  Наверное, для решения  вопросов, подобных заданному,  нужно  работать не только со словарями, но и  изучать практические тексты. Непонятно, откуда вообще могло впоследствии взяться  написание "казачёк" да еще попасть в словарь.

Answer (score 1):

По Лопатину, а именно он сейчас в приоритете, казачок, да и по всем современным словарям.

По Вашим ссылкам 1- Казачий словарь-справочник. — Сан. Ансельмо, Калифорния, С.Ш.А.. Составитель словаря Г.В.Губарев, редактор - издатель А.И.Скрылов. 1966-1970.    Это иностранное издательство, оно часто сохраняет устаревшее написание слов, а 0-е-ё до революции было неустоявшимся правилом, Например, Кондрашев читалось как "Кондрашов".

е-ё вообще была одна буква, отсюда написание казачек.

Словарь Тришина претенциозный, он имел целью войти в Книгу рекордов, и вошёл- как самый полный словарь синонимов. При составлении словаря использованы изданные словари: орфографические, синонимические, фразеологических синонимов, толковые, начиная со «Словаря русского языка XVIII в.» и «Толко́вого слова́ря живо́го великору́сского языка́» В.И. Даля , церковно-славянских слов, а также иностранных слов, неузуальных слов, арго (кроме заведомо ненормативной лексики), и т.п. Кроме того, для пополнения словаря активно использовались газеты, журналы, Интернет, словари поисковиков Yandex и Google путём анализа выдачи их автоподсказчиков слов (с проверкой по другим источникам).

То есть синонимами в ДАННОМ словаре могут быть не только слова и словосочетания современного общеупотребительного языка, но и устаревшие слова, просторечные, жаргонные, областные, слова профессиональной речи и т.п. Он собрал всё, что кем-то когда-то употреблялось, если даже кто-то с ошибкой написал, слово уже входило в словарь и объяснялось через правильное слово как синоним.http://www.trishin.ru/left/dictionary/  Так что он не может быть эталоном правописания.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое всем ответившим на мой вопрос: Серж, Vera, slava1947, Людмила!
Особенно:
- slava1947 - за невероятно интересное историко-филологическое эссе;
- Людмила - за острое, с легким налетом сарказма, описание словаря Тришина.